# jQuery selector [id=variable] not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, selector

I am needing to find an HTML element with an id that comes from 2 different pieces of data. I am trying to form the selector name with a variable and passing it through to the selector but it is not working. I am doing it this way because jQuery doesn't allow selectors with spaces and you have to do it this way if you have an ID with spaces.

```
angular.forEach($scope.eventMapByDate, function (zoneWithTooltip, date_key) {
    angular.forEach(zoneWithTooltip, function(zoneEventInfo, zoneID){
        $timeout(function () {
            var eventElem = date_key + "-" + zoneEventInfo.zone_name;
            $('span[id=eventElem]').find('span').html("<i class=\"fa fa-bullhorn\"></i> " + zoneEventInfo.length);
        }, 500)
     });
});
```

Comment: *Nothing* allows id values with spaces.

Comment: String concatenation! `$('span[id="' + eventElem + '"]')`

Comment: Space characters are the **only** characters which are forbidden in ID attributes. Fix your HTML, don't try to hack around it. — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: I m not sure if you are trying to get a span inside span with id or you want to change the html inside the same span.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span[id="' + eventElem + '"]')
```

try this problem will solve it is string concatenation problem